# Spring's MockHttpServlet(Request|Response) alternatives?

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking

In 'spring-test' there's mock classes for unit testing Servlets, which is very useful. Unfortuately, I do not need any of the other Spring componenets, and do not wish to depend on spring-core in my project.

It is possible to either:

- Use spring-test without depending on spring-core, ... (i.e sever the mocking-classes from spring)?
- Use an alternative mock library with similar functionality?

Comment: I have tried option no 1, to sever the mocking spring*mock.web.* classes from spring, without success. there's loads of dependencies on classes found in spring-core which makes this hard.

Comment: Using a mock framework like mockito wouldn't do the trick?

Comment: I need to be able to read whatever is written to the outputstream of MockHttpServletResponse, in fact, it needs to act and behave like a read HttpServlet(Request|Response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the project [Mockrunner](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/), which is designed for testing J2EE components such as servlets, and which includes MockHttpServletRequest and Response objects.

Comment: In the continuation I will factor most/all of the logic out of the controller. I realize I have indulged in bad design practices.